# some scripts not loading in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code is only working in Firefox; it displays all of the alerts and runs the displayUserLanding function successfully. In IE the browser only seems to run the:

**alert("Helper Loaded")**

My code is as follows:

```
<script>            
    $(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'js/helper.js',
            dataType: "script",
            success:function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'js/user_landing/user_landing.js',
                    dataType: "script",
                    success:function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'js/case_det/case_form.js',
                            dataType: "script",
                            success:function() {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'js/case_det/load_case_det.js',
                                    dataType: "script",
                                    success:function() {
                                        console.log("All forms loaded. Now call function");
                                        alert("All forms loaded. Now call function");
                                        displayUserLanding();
                                    }
                                });
                                console.log("Case form loaded");
                                alert("Case form loaded");
                            }
                        });
                        console.log("UL loaded");
                        alert("UL loaded");
                    }
                });
                console.log("Helper loaded");
                alert("Helper Loaded");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

﻿Can somebody please advise what I am doing wrong.The ﻿﻿displayUserLanding ﻿function resides in the user_landing.js file. This function refers to other functions that exist in the other scripts. My code is as follows:
JavaScript

Thank you

Comment: that's one pretty pyramid. Do you have any mesages on the developer tools console?

Comment: Better use jquery promise

Comment: Hi both. No errors occur in either Firebug or IE. I can look into JQuery promise but it would be good to understand what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to advise that the error was caused by a missing bracket in the user_landing.js file and when I refreshed my IE browser, it did produce an error indicating that. Firefox, however, didn't seem to care.